# Username and password iteration in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have been trying to think of a way to iterate through a username list and check each value of password from a password list. For example, there is a list of 2 usernames, **admin** and **root**, there is also a password list of 5 passwords.

For each of the usernames all passwords will have to checked.

I have been able to come up with this piece of code:

```
if os.path.isfile(USER_FILE) and os.path.isfile(PASS_FILE):
    with open(USER_FILE, 'r') as user_file, open(PASS_FILE, 'r') as pass_file:
        for u in user_file.read().splitlines():
            for p in pass_file.read().splitlines():
                print(f"{u}:{p}")
```

However, after the first username the scripts stops and the 2nd username is not checked agains all passwords in my list.

The output I am getting from the script is as follows:

```
./brute.py users.txt passwd.txt
admin:root
admin:admin
admin:toor
admin:123456
admin:000000000
admin:password
```

Any suggestion is appreciated..

Comment: Please add the sample contents of the first file. As a side note, I do not see where you _check_ anything. You simply print all pairs of names and passwords.

Comment: You can't keep calling `pass_file.read()` on the same file inside the loop. Once you've read through it once the iterator is spent. You are probably better off using `itertools.product` for this.

Comment: Sample contents of username list: 
    admin
    root